# Calculating Late Fees with a nested IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a spreadsheet that can determine how much a homeowner owes in association dues. Fairly simple, but the problem I'm having is getting the "monthly dues forward" cell (where the formula below resides and tells me how much is still owed after the payment, or lack thereof, to carry forward to the next month) to calculate the late fees correctly. If someone is late they get a flat $5 late fee. If they don't pay that fee in the following month it becomes $10 ($5+$5) and so on. And, if they don't pay this month either the $10 is added to $5 (for this month) plus any shortage in recurring monthly fees paid. The fee is $80 monthly.
Here is what I have come up with. Right now it returns a value of "FALSE":

```
=IF(E8<Master!$H$3,IF(D8>Master!$H$3,      
(D8-E8)+10,IF(E8>Master!$H$3,IF(D8>Master!$H$3,
(D8-E8)+5,IF(E8<Master!$H$3,IF(D8=Master!$H$3,(D8-E8)+5,D8-E8))))))
```

**Some notes:**

Master!$H$3 represents the monthly fee of $80.

E8 represents the amount paid for the month.

D8 represents the amount owed for the month

Comment: Your second to last IF statement, `IF(E8<Master!$H$3,IF(D8=Master!$H$3,(D8-E8)+5,D8-E8)` doesn't have a condition for the FALSE case.

Comment: If you want to compound fees over various months, there must be other rows with data for these months. You can't solve this by looking just at this one row. Post more information about your spreadsheet architecture. Maybe a screenshot would help. A sample file would definitely help. Think file sharing service (dropbox, onedrive, avoid the spammy ones), upload, post a link.

Comment: Delete your excel-VBA tag ... this isn't a vba or macro related question.

Answer (score 0):

By using Alt-Enter in the Excel formula box to format your statement, it is now clear that you have only supplied True & False outcomes for the 2nd, 4th & 6th IF statements. The 1st, 3rd and 5th have an IF statement for their True outcome, but no False outcome has been supplied.

```
=IF(E8<Master!$H$3,
         IF(D8>Master!$H$3,
               (D8-E8)+10,
               IF(E8>Master!$H$3,
                    IF(D8>Master!$H$3,
                           (D8-E8)+5,
                           IF(E8<Master!$H$3,
                                 IF(D8=Master!$H$3,
                                        (D8-E8)+5,
                                        D8-E8
                                  )
                            )
                     )
               )
         )
  )
```